# upload csv and export to other location

Tags: reactjs, laravel, export-to-csv

I am trying to upload csv file (80mb, 500k rows) form react and want to store at laravel storage folder in local system. i have used csvreader and papaparseoptions to get csv data, store it in array and send data through api to laravel side

```
    var arr = [];
    csvdata.forEach(element => {
        arr.push(element)
    });

    //uploadCSV api 
    fetch(url, {
        body: JSON.stringify({'uploadedData': arr}),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {

        console.log(json)
    })
```

and on laravel side

```
    Storage::put('contacts.csv', $request->get('uploadedData'));
    return response()->json(['message' =>$request->All()], 200);
```

but on laravel side it gave me error one time

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 9709677 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

I do not even agree that sending large data through api is good option. i searched but missing something relevant

what more can i try alternate to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The message was clear, it's a PHP issue, not Laravel.

By default, 8388608 bytes (8MB), is the limit of the data size you can send via a POST request. You can change this configuration on your **`php.ini`** file changed `post_max_size` config.

Another related configuration is `upload_max_filesize` that is the limit size if you are uploading a file.

You can increase this limits to 1GB for example. Open your `php.ini` file and change these lines:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M;
post_max_size = 1000M;
```

Then, **save the file** and **restart** your webserver to load the new configurations.